# Stop the ioloop of SelectConnection in Pika (RabbitMQ) from blocking

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

Can anyone help me understand how I can create a Connection Class for RabbitMQ that is non blocking (i.e. I can create and start the connection then start running other parts of the code?)

I've modified the excellent SelectConnection eamples in Pika to enable callbacks to handle unexpected Connection Closures, and Created an `RmqConnect` class which successfully connects and will reconnect on a closure by the RabbitMQ server

```py
class RmqConnection():
    def __init__(self):
        self._connection = None
        self._stopping = False
   def connect(self):
        """
        An endless loop to Keep reconnecting to RabbitMQ
        if the connection is closed
        """
        while not self._stopping:
            self._connection = None
            log.info('Connecting to %s', CON_PARAMS.host)
            self._connection = pika.SelectConnection(
                CON_PARAMS,
                on_open_callback=self.on_connection_open,
                on_open_error_callback=self.on_connection_open_error,
                on_close_callback=self.on_connection_closed)
            try:
                self._connection.ioloop.start()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self.close()
                if (self._connection is not None and
                        not self._connection.is_closed):
                    # Finish closing
                    self._connection.ioloop.start()
```

Then as a test I'm trying to create an instance of `RmqConnection`

```
def main():
    connection = RmqConnection()
    connection.connect()
    print ("We never get here until the connect() method returns")
```

Ideally I'm trying to create a connection object in the `RmqConnection` Class and make this available to other parts of my program after connecting and starting the ioloop of the Select Connection.

However the `self._connection.ioloop.start()` call seems to block and my connect() method never returns whilst the connection is open. Only returns once I close with the KeyboardInteerupt.

Any ideas of how I could restructure this better and enable the functionality I'm after (i.e set up a connection with the SelectConnection callbacks, start an ioloop and then continue with my program?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've (hesitantly) got a fix that seems to work for now. I'm concerned it's not thread safe however.

Basically I start the `SelectConnection.ioloop.start()` method that was blocking in it's own thread. Then I am free to return the connection object and use it elsewhere.

```py
class RmqConnection():

    def __init__(self):
        self._connection = None
        self._stopping = False

    def connect(self):
        """
        Create a connection, start the ioloop to connect
        inside a thread and then return the connection
        """
        log.info('Connecting to %s', CON_PARAMS.host)
        self._connection = pika.SelectConnection(
            CON_PARAMS,
            on_open_callback=self.on_connection_open,
            on_open_error_callback=self.on_connection_open_error,
            on_close_callback=self.on_connection_closed)

        self.iothread = threading.Thread(
            target=self._connection.ioloop.start,
            args=())
        self.iothread.start()

        return self._connection
```

and then in bpython I can seem to get the connection object (which is now running in a seperate ioloop in a thread) and add and delete queues and publish messages.

```py
bpython version 0.20.1 on top of Python 3.6.9 /usr/bin/python3
>>> import connect_rmq
>>> test_conn=connect_rmq.RmqConnection()
>>> connection=test_conn.connect()
>>> mychannel = connection.channel()
>>> mychannel.close()
>>> mychannel = connection.channel()
>>> mychannel.basic_publish(exchange='rmq.telemetry', routing_key='', body='HELLO')
>>>
```

If anyone can see any issues with this please do shout!